# Failing to load Mesh in Gazebo Garden

Tags: gazebo

I've been upgrading for gazebo Fortress to Garden. Now my SDF file isn't loading and I am receiving the following error:

```
[Dbg] [SDFFeatures.cc:328] Mesh construction from an SDF has not been implemented yet for dartsim. Use AttachMeshShapeFeature to use mesh shapes.
[Err] [SDFFeatures.cc:843] The geometry element of collision [plane_col] couldn't be created
```

My sdf file for my plane model looks like this:

```
<sdf version="1.5">
<model name="plane">
    <static>true</static>
    <link name="plane_link">
        <visual name="plane_visual">
            <pose>-10 -10 -1 0 0 0</pose>
            <geometry>
                <mesh>
                    <uri>plane.stl</uri>
                    <scale>1 1 1</scale>
                </mesh>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision name="plane_col">
            <pose>-10 -10 -1 0 0 0</pose>
            <geometry>
                <mesh>
                    <uri>plane.stl</uri>
                    <scale>1 1 1</scale>
                </mesh>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <sensor name="touch_sensor" type="contact">
            <contact>
                <collision>plane_col</collision>
            </contact>
        </sensor>
    </link>
    <plugin filename="gz-sim-touchplugin-system" name="gz::sim::systems::TouchPlugin">
        <target>robot::base</target>
        <namespace>floor</namespace>
        <time>0.001</time>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </plugin>
</model>
```

This model is being included by uri in my world sdf file.

This was all working fine in Fortress - is there something I need to change for Garden?

Comment: The error msg: `[Err] [SDFFeatures.cc:843] The geometry element of collision [plane_col] couldn't be created` is misleading. The mesh collision should still be loaded. I recently created a PR to change it to debug msg: https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-physics/pull/531. One thing to try is use another mesh (or a box geom) just to check if it's an issue with the stl mesh. Otherwise the problem could be somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, yes it was another issue. Thanks